# There are more than three data in one of the cells that are bit formats

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, check-constraints

I need to have **Select up to 3 company Types** in SQL and use **check constrain**.
How to do this, or I also accept other suggestions., For the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Dbo.[CompanyType](
    [TypeID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Manufacturer] [bit] NULL,
    [Trading] [bit] NULL,
    [BuyingOffice] [bit] NULL,
    [Agent] [bit] NULL,
    [Wholesaler] [bit] NULL,
    [Commission] [bit] NULL,
    [Association] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [BusinessService] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Other] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Photo] [image] NULL,
    [CreateDate] datetime
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CompanyType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TypeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.[CompanyType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Company_PersianTax]  DEFAULT ((9)) FOR [Taxpercent]
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.[CompanyType] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Company_CreateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreateDate]
GO
```

1. using a check constrain.

> How to use check constrain for this model??

I tried by :

2. In the meantime I use SP to insert. Isn't it better to check for three or more true data there? At the moment of data entry as a parameter check

```
--parameter validation
if(@Manufacturer+@Trading+@BuyingOffice+@Agent+@Wholesaler+@Commission+@Association+@BusinessService+@Other)<= 3

Begin
  Return
End
else 

insert statement (...)
```

3. Using trigger like following query! check inserted, sum of column <= 3 rolback

```
CREATE TRIGGER usp_checksum3
   ON  dbo.companytype
   AFTER insert
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     if     (Select [Manufacturer]+[Trading]+[BuyingOffice]+[Agent]+[Wholesaler]+[Commission]+[Association]+[BusinessService]+[Other] 
     From inserted) <= 3    

  Return

END
```

Thanks for your tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the following check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Dbo.[CompanyType](
    [TypeID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Manufacturer] [bit] NULL,
    [Trading] [bit] NULL,
    [BuyingOffice] [bit] NULL,
    [Agent] [bit] NULL,
    [Wholesaler] [bit] NULL,
    [Commission] [bit] NULL,
    [Association] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [BusinessService] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Other] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Photo] [image] NULL,
    [CreateDate] datetime
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CompanyType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TypeID] ASC)
    WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, 
        OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Company_Types] CHECK (
        CAST([Manufacturer] AS INT) 
        + CAST([Trading] AS INT) 
        + CAST([BuyingOffice] AS INT) 
        + CAST([Agent] AS INT)
        + CAST([Wholesaler] AS INT) 
        + CAST([Commission] AS INT)
        + CAST([Association] AS INT)
        + CAST([BusinessService] AS INT)
        + CAST([Other] AS INT)
    <= 3)
```

You don't need to implement additional logic in your stored procedure. The check constraint guarantees integrity, and apply equally to inserts performed from the SP or outside.

If you want to modify the existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE Dbo.[CompanyType] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [Chk_CompanyType] CHECK (
    CAST([Manufacturer] AS INT) 
    + CAST([Trading] AS INT) 
    + CAST([BuyingOffice] AS INT) 
    + CAST([Agent] AS INT)
    + CAST([Wholesaler] AS INT) 
    + CAST([Commission] AS INT)
    + CAST([Association] AS INT)
    + CAST([BusinessService] AS INT)
    + CAST([Other] AS INT)
<= 3)
```

Comment: @Amirhossein . . . This is a very reasonable solution but you should declare all the bit columns as `NOT NULL`.